# Solving a differential equation problem with boundary conditions

Tags: problem-solving, differential

I need to solve this differential equation with precise BC:

**u′′(x)=ζ−ξ^2*u(x)**

**u(a)=v1**

**u′(a)=v1sech(χ⋅a)sinh(χ⋅a)**

The solution of this problem provide the slip function u(x) in a mode - 2 Fracture mechanics approach analytical model to investigate bond behaviour in composite materials systems.

However, after many tries I still haven't found a close form solution of the function.

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: write the general solution as $u(x) = \zeta/\xi^2 + c_1 \cos(\xi (x-a)) + c_2 \sin(\xi (x-a))$.

Comment: Thank you very much!